# Java: Unmapped target property error (not warning)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm working with a piece of code that gives me a build failure (in IntelliJ).
There are no reds or other indications of errors, but it fails when I build the application.

The error:

```
java: Unmapped target property: "removeLaneAreneItem". Mapping from property "LaneBudsjett laneBudsjettAnnenBank" to "LaneBudsjettTO laneBudsjettAnnenBank".
```

The code:

```
@Mapping(target = "removeLaneAreneItem", ignore = true)
LaneBudsjettTO laneBudsjett(no.husbanken.saksbehandling.simulering.domain.LaneBudsjett v1);
```

All I seem to be able to find about this is about warnings, not errors. Also, the mapping target and "ignore=true I though would solve the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should tag your question with whatever mapping library you're using, and show the import statement for the annotation.